# orgmode - resize inline image in windows

Tags: org-mode

I have installed emacs27 on windows from official release. when I run orgmode with inline image, the image do not resize according to width attribute (400 as below example)!

```
#+attr_org: :width 400
#+attr_latex: :width 400
#+attr_html: :width 400
[[./sample.png]]
```

[image]

Then I search orgmode source code and found below section (lisp/org.el):

```
(defcustom org-preview-latex-process-alist
  '((dvipng
     :programs ("latex" "dvipng")
     ...
     (imagemagick
     :programs ("latex" "convert")
     :description "pdf > png"
     :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick."
     :image-input-type "pdf"
     :image-output-type "png"
     :image-size-adjust (1.0 . 1.0)
     :latex-compiler ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
     :image-converter
     ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
  :group 'org-latex
  :version "26.1"
  :package-version '(Org . "9.0")
  :type '(alist :tag "LaTeX to image backends"
        :value-type (plist)))
```

I have installed imagick.exe and the convert command should be "magick convert". I need to customize the image-converter to below line:

```
("magick.exe convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
```

Is it possible to customize it in init.el file? Or any other proper way to call "magick.exe convert" instead of "convert"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easier to use `Customize` on the variable: say `C-h v org-preview-latex-process-alist`, click on the `customize` link, scroll down to the `ImageMagick` section, find the `:image-converter` property and change its value; then save the customization for this and future sessions.

If you are intent on doing it manually, try the following in your `init.el`:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (plist-put 
    (cdr (assq 'imagemagick org-preview-latex-process-alist)) 
    :image-converter '("magick.exe convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
```

Disclaimer: all this shows is how to change the property. I don't run Windows, so I have not tested the command itself.

Comment: Thanks, looks like (image-type-available-p 'imagemagick) return nil, then that logic has been skipped. I need to find a emacs with imagemagick enable!